# Is it possible to find who created and who last modified the Infopath form template for a SharePoint library?

Tags: infopath

I would like to find the user who has created/uploaded the infopath template and who last modified that template file. Is it possible to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the site with SharePoint Designer.

On the left, click on All Files, then navigate to your library.  Once there, click on the Forms folder, in there you should see a template.xsn file along with when and who modified it.

If the form is published as a content type, navigate to that library and you will find your details.

You should also be able to access this info using PowerShell.

Comment: One should be warned: **DON'T** try the SPDesigner method if your list is very large. It can cause the list to hang, returning 401 errors on all hits until you do an IIS Restart on the server.

Comment: the list/library do not open if the items are more than 5000 in the sharepoint deisgner when navigated via All files